# how to retrieve data from mysql in android studio

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am making an app where i want to see statistics about a local club and show it in a TableLayout

I am new at android studio and i dont really know how. I have tried a lot but i feel like i am missing something..

Here is what i have done so far:

my php file (called text.php):

```
<?php
$servername = "myServername";
$username = "myUsername";
$password = "myPassword";
$dbname = "myDbName";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Player_name, Goals, Assists, Yellow_cards, Red_cards FROM Statistics";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<br> Player_name: ". $row["Player_name"]. " - Goals: ". $row["Goals"]. " Assists: ". $row["Assists"]. " - Yellow_cards: ". $row["Yellow_cards"]. " - Red_cards: ". $row["Red_cards"]. "<br>";
             "<br> Assists ". $row["Assists"]. " - Goals: ". $row["Goals"]. " " . $row["Assists"] . "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

My StatisticActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import java.util.ArrayList;



public class StatisticActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GridView gv;
    private ArrayList<String> players;
    private JSONArray result;

    TextView name, goals, assists, yellowCards, redCards;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_statistic);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTr);
        goals = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.GoalsTr);
        assists = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.AssistTr);
        yellowCards = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yellowTr);
        redCards = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.redTr);

        HttpURLConnectionHandler handler = new HttpURLConnectionHandler();
        String response = handler.sendText("this is a text");

    }

}
```

My HttpURLConnectionHandler class:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.ProtocolException;
import java.net.URL;


public class HttpURLConnectionHandler {

    protected String urlG = "myUrlAddress";
    public String sendText(String text){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlG + "text.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(text);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            return response.toString();
        }
            catch(Exception e){return "error";}
    }
}
```

I dont know if there is something wrong with my php script or in my code or something else that i am missing.

Hope someone can help

Comment: Can you tell us/add what kind of errors this gives you?

Comment: I am getting this at    
     DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    conn.getOutputStream()); 

Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.android.okhttp.HttpUrl$Builder.toString()

Answer (score -1):

Do you want to fetch data from your server or you want to send data to it ?

If you want to **see** statistics on your app, then you need to use `InputStream` rather than `OutputStream` and eventually you need to `read` rather than to `write`.

- Don't use `HTML` in transporting your data from end-to-end, but rather use [JSON](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.json.php).
- Execute your Network related operation in [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), the execution of `sendText` method will eventually throw a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

I suggest you invest some of your time in learning the basics of android, also start with simple apps before moving to relatively complicated aspects.